# IOS/Xcode/Storyboard/Autolayout: PickerView not Scrolling possibly due to Autolayout Constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, uipickerview

I have a pickerView created in Storyboard embedded in a scrollview and the pickerView is not responding to touches.  I believe the reason is that the pickerView extends below what the Visual Debugger shows to be the size of its superview, the UIView in which it is embedded--See image.

[image]

What I don't understand, however, is why the superview is so small. Its height is constrained to a UIScrollView, one level up which is much larger.  The scrollview, in turn, is constrained to the height of the overall View which is also much larger.  When you look at the Storyboard the superview of the PickerView appears to be fully large enough.  See image. The only thing that I can think of is that the midpoint of the container is somehow meaningful.  The upper half above the midpoint seems to correspond with the size of the superview in the Visual Debugger.

[image]

I cannot figure this one out and am stumped on what to change.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I think you need to set the `contentSize` of scroll view. Auto Layout and scroll views is complicated.

Comment: I have set the contentSize and tried various settings without effect.  The autolayout seems to override them.  Do you have any idea why the UIView is blue only to where it shows in the first pic?.  Is that its size or is it just showing upper half?

Comment: That look like its size. You can check the frame in the size pane on the right side of the view debugger. Have you tried to add a height constraint to the picker view?

Comment: Well, I have solved the issue, it appears-not sure why--by removing a constraint, view height = scrollview height.  There are still constraints view top=scrollview top and view bottom = scrollview bottom.  (there is a height on the pickerview).  Doesn't make any sense but hey.